# Inconsistency in has_unique_object_representations and empty subobjects

Tags: c++, c++20, type-traits, object-identity

I've playing around with C++20's [`[[no_unique_address]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address) attribute and found some interesting behavior when using it with the [`has_unique_object_representations`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/has_unique_object_representations) type trait:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

struct Empty {};

struct A : public Empty {
    int x;
};

struct B {
    [[no_unique_address]] Empty e;
    int x;
};

static_assert (sizeof(A) == sizeof(int));
static_assert (sizeof(B) == sizeof(int));

static_assert(std::has_unique_object_representations_v<A>);
static_assert(std::has_unique_object_representations_v<B>);
```

Only the last assertion fails with both GCC (trunk) and Clang (trunk). As far as I can tell, there's no reason for `A` and `B` to behave differently here.

Is this a compiler bug or is there a reason for this difference?

Comment: Seems like a bug. The whole point of `[[no_unique_address]]` is to be able to write `B` instead of `A`, and as you showed, it's not like `B` has some padding somewhere to allow for non-unique representations. Filed [97285](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97285).

Comment: Added a bug also for clang [47722](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=47722).

Comment: Thanks for the answers and for submitting the bug reports! @Barry could you also submit this as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks!